# How to reverse the Array in Python

Tags: python

In Python
How to write the following program:

From an array for following words in the given Order and reverse it from middle in both direction and display it

```
InputArray = ['Good', 'better', 'Best', 'Fanstatic', 'perfect', 'Super', 'Fine', 'Great' ]

Output = [ 'Fanstatic', 'Best', 'Better', 'Good', 'Great', 'Fine', 'Super', 'Perfect' ]
```

Comment: Have you tried something that didn't work?

Answer (score 3):

```
l1 = ['Good', 'better', 'Best', 'Fanstatic', 'perfect', 'Super', 'Fine', 'Great']
hlength = len(l1)//2
print inputArray[:hlength][::-1] + inputArray[hlength:][::-1]
```

**Output**

```
['Fanstatic', 'Best', 'better', 'Good', 'Great', 'Fine', 'Super', 'perfect']
```

Comment: Use // to avoid potential TypeError here on py3

Answer (score 2):

Use `reverse()` function

```
>>> InputArray = ['Good', 'better', 'Best', 'Fantastic', 'perfect', 'Super', 'Fine', 'Great']
>>> middle = len(InputArray)/2
>>> Output = InputArray[middle:] + InputArray[:middle] # swap the last half with the first half
>>> Output.reverse() # reverse the list in-place
>>> Output
['Fantastic', 'Best', 'better', 'Good', 'Great', 'Fine', 'Super', 'perfect']
```

**Explanation:**

`InputArray[middle:]` returns a sub-list starting from index `middle` to the end
`InputArray[:middle]` returns a sub-list starting from index 0 to `middle - 1`

or you can use this one-liner

```
>>> Output = InputArray[middle-1::-1] + InputArray[:middle-1:-1]
>>> Output
['Fantastic', 'Best', 'better', 'Good', 'Great', 'Fine', 'Super', 'perfect']
```

**Explanation:**

`InputArray[middle-1::-1]` returns a sub-list starting from index `middle-1` to 0
`InputArray[:middle-1:-1]` returns a sub-list starting from index end to `middle - 1`

`[start:end:step_size]` the third parameter sets the step-size to `-1` hence the reversed order.

Comment: This reverses an array, but I suspect that's not the question. Not that the question is very clear... How do you interpret " reverse it from middle in both direction "?

Comment: changed the code accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Or you can Try This :

```
InputArray = ['Good', 'better', 'Best', 'Fanstatic', 'perfect', 'Super', 'Fine', 'Great' ]
for i in reversed(InputArray):
  OutputArray = i
  print OutputArray
```

Comment: Does this give the required output?

Comment: @doctorlove Yeap you can check the output here ... http://www.compileonline.com/execute_python_online.php

Answer (score 0):

```
m = len(InputArray)/2
OutputArray = InputArray[0:m][::-1]+InputArray[m::][::-1]
```

Output for given input:

```
['Fanstatic', 'Best', 'better', 'Good', 'Great', 'Fine', 'Super', 'perfect']
```